# How do I find transconductance from a biased circuit?

Tags: amplifier, bias, pnp, biasing, transconductance

I am new to biasing and have trouble finding the transconductance \$ g_{m1}' \$ for this biased differential amplifier below.

I know that \$ V_{BE} = 0.6\$ V and \$ g_{m1}' = \frac{I_c}{V_T} \$ but that is about it. I also see that 2 ***pnp*** BJTs are used for the differential amplifier, if that makes any difference.

**How do I calculate** \$ g_{m1}' \$ **?**

[image]

Comment: You know Vbe, then you can calculate how much voltage is across that 1 k ohm resistor. Then use Ohm's law to calculate the current. That's the current for **both** transistors. Also calculate how much voltage drops across those 0.1 k resistors. Then calculate what the Vce of the transistors will be. Determine if that Vce is large enough for the PNPs to operate in active mode.

Comment: **Am I doing this right?**. Voltage at the base of one of the transistors is 4V - 2.6V = 1.4V. Voltage at the emitter is 1.4V - 0.6V = 0.8V. Voltage across the 1k ohm resistor is 4V - 0.8V = 3.2V and the current through it is 3.2V/1000kOhm = 3.2mA. Then half of the current passes through one transistor 3.2mA/2 = 1.6mA (assuming that base current=0). That current passes through 0.1kOhm resistor which means that voltage drop across it is 0.1kOhm * 1.6mA = 0.16V which is also the voltage at the collector of the transistor. The collector emitter voltage \$ V_{CE}\$ is then 0.16V - 0.8V = -0.64V.

Comment: @cr1901 why can I just remove them?

Comment: @Clone I didn't read the question properly. Removed my comment.

Comment: The voltage at the base is equal to 4V - 2.6V = 1.4V and the voltage at PNP emitter is 0.6V higher the base voltage. Ve = 1.4V + 0.6V = 2V. The Voltage across the 1k ohm resistor is equal to 4V - 2V = 2V, so the current is 2mA. And because the base voltage is the same for both transistors, the 1K ohm resistor current is split in half between transistors Ic1 = Ic2 = 2mA/2 = 1mA. And finally gm1 = Ic/Vt = 1mA/25mV = 40mS